How to convert binary, previously converted from SQLite .db file back to .db in Python
I'm trying around to see if I can steganographically hide a database inside an image. I managed to convert the original .db file in binary, but my stegunhide function doesn't do that, instead converting to a text file with binary inside and the ending (dot)db. Any help is appreciated :)
def steghide():
    db_location = input("Enter the path to the .db file: ")
    try:
        os.path.isfile(db_location)
        with open(db_location, "rb") as file:
            content = file.read()
        binary_db = ''.join(f"{byte:>08b}" for byte in content)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
    img_location = input("Enter the path to the .png file: ")
    try:
        os.path.isfile(img_location)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
    image = PIL.Image.open(img_location, 'r')
    width, height = image.size
    img_arr = np.array(list(image.getdata()))

    if image.mode == "P":
        print("Error: Paletted images not supported. ")
        exit()

    channels = 4 if image.mode == "RGBA" else 3

    pixels = img_arr.size // channels


    indicator = "$STEGPASS$"

    binary_db += indicator
    byte_db = ''.join(f"{ord(c):08b}" for c in binary_db)
    bits = len(byte_db)

    if bits > pixels:
        print("Error: Not enough space within image.")
    else:
        index = 0
        for i in range(pixels):
            for j in range(0, 3):
                if index < bits:
                    img_arr[i][j] = int(bin(img_arr[i][j])[2:-1] + byte_db[index], 2)
                    index += 1

    img_arr = img_arr.reshape((height, width, channels))
    result = PIL.Image.fromarray(img_arr.astype('uint8'), image.mode)
    result.save('encoded.png')


def stegunhide():
    img_location = input("Enter the path to the .png file: ")
    try:
        os.path.isfile(img_location)
        image = PIL.Image.open(img_location, 'r')
        img_arr = np.array(list(image.getdata()))
        if image.mode == "P":
            print("Error: Paletted images not supported. ")
            exit()
        channels = 4 if image.mode == "RGBA" else 3
        pixels = img_arr.size // channels

        secret_bits = [bin(img_arr[i][j])[-1] for i in range(pixels) for j in range(0,3)]
        secret_bits = ''.join(secret_bits)
        secret_bits = [secret_bits[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(secret_bits), 8)]

        database = [chr(int(secret_bits[i], 2)) for i in range(len(secret_bits))]
        database = ''.join(database)
        indicator = "$STEGPASS$"

        if indicator in database:
            db_content = database[:database.index(indicator)]
            with open('decrypted.db', "wb") as file:
                file.write(db_content.encode())
        else:
            print('Error: No database found.')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error:', e)


Honestly, I have no idea as to how to go on about this problem.

content already contains the binary content. binary_db isn't binary at all, it's a string containing the hex values of the bytes. The rest of the code shows the same mistake - byte_db isn't the binary content, it's a string with the hex values of the bytes. secret_bits is a string, not the bytes.

Thank you so much! I had figured so much as that I had used the types wrong after a while but got stuck there. Thank you for your comment and have a great week!
